# Handler assigned via onclick attribute is not getting invoked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know WHAT the problem is, but the JavaScript isn't getting executed! I tried it many times, but I don't see any error in it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Log In Page</title>
<script>
function myf()
{
document.getElementById("name").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("reason").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("register").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("link").display="inline";
alert("You have successfully registered.");
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<center><h1 style="font-family:Agency FB;font-size:100px;color:#3333FF;letter-spacing:50px;text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #FF9933;">My Profile</h1></center>
<center><p style="font-family:Ubuntu Mono Bold;color:#3333FF;">You are requested to FILL IN these particulars.</p></center>
<font color="#07C6F6" face="Arial">
<center>Enter Your Name:<input type="text" id="name"><br><br>
Why Do You Want to See This Profile:<input type="text" id="reason"><br></center>
</font>
<br>
<br>
<center><button type="button" id="register" onClick="myF()">Register Info</button><br>
<p id="link" style="font-family:Arial;display:none;"><a href="Profile.html">View Profile</a></p></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `myf` is not the same as `myF`.

Comment: you question title looks more like an advertisement, change it. add some more details like what are you trying to do, what you got etc.

Comment: off topic, why are you using font and center tags, they are supposed to be dead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <button type="button" id="register" onClick="myF()">Register Info</button>
```

change your calling function myF() to myf()

It will work.

Comment: I did it. thanks! but the document.getElementById("link").display="inline"; isnt working!

Comment: @user2885253: You need `.style.display = "inline"`, and probably some basic lessons as well as a little more effort on your part in research and troubleshooting.

Comment: document.getElementById("link").style.display="inline"; use it like this.

Answer (score 0):

As you have wrote function in wrong format write it in the form of Camel cases 
you have wrote function as  myf() write it as myF()...

at the place of button you have written correct write same as usually at function creation..

it is going to work

Answer (score 0):

You just need to correct the method call in button's onClick. its myF()